# Is there a way to implement SES sending authorization in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses, aws-cdk

I am searching for the way to implement sending authorization/delegate sender in a purely IaaC way using AWS-CDK as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization.html

It is possible to create iam.PolicyDocument from JSON given in the AWS docs, however I cannot find a way to attach it to the domain identity of the SES in aws-ses nor aws-iam packages.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found this npm package while trying to implement on AWS CDK the SES sending authorization for an email address:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk-ses-domain-identity

It promises to implement the validation of the SES sending authorization for domains, so maybe it could be useful to you.

Regards.